# How can i make button in table cell using NiceGui library?

Tags: python, python-3.x, ag-grid, justpy, nicegui

```py
from nicegui import ui
```

Called when a button in a cell is clicked:

```py
def buttonClick(*args):
    print(args)
    
table = ui.table({
    'columnDefs': [
        {'headerName': 'Task id', 'field': 'taskId'},
```

This is how i am trying to add a button to the table:

```py
        {
            'headerName': "Info",
            'field': "info", 
            'cellRenderer': 'buttonRenderer',
            'cellRendererParams': {
                'onClick': buttonClick,
                'label': 'Check',
            }
        },
    ],
    'rowData': [
        {
            'taskId': 1,
        },
    ],
})
    
ui.run()
```

I get an exception:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/stanislav/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/starlette/websockets.py", line 171, in send_json
    text = json.dumps(data)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/json/__init__.py", line 231, in dumps
    return _default_encoder.encode(obj)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/json/encoder.py", line 199, in encode
    chunks = self.iterencode(o, _one_shot=True)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/json/encoder.py", line 257, in iterencode
    return _iterencode(o, 0)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/json/encoder.py", line 179, in default
    raise TypeError(f'Object of type {o.__class__.__name__} '
TypeError: Object of type function is not JSON serializable
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Currently custom button renderers are not supported in [NiceGUI](https://nicegui.io/). This is due to a missing renderer in JustPy, which only provides a `checkboxRenderer`.

But via the underlying JustPy view you can at least register a handler for the `cellClicked` event:

```py
from nicegui import ui

table = ui.table({
    'columnDefs': [
        {'headerName': 'Task id', 'field': 'taskId'},
        {'headerName': 'Info', 'field': 'info'},
    ],
    'rowData': [
        {'taskId': 1},
    ],
})

def handle_click(sender, msg):
    print(sender)
    print(msg)

table.view.on('cellClicked', handle_click)

ui.run()
```

The output contains plenty information about which cell has been clicked:

```
AgGrid(id: 1, vue_type: grid, Grid options: {'columnDefs': [{'headerName': 'Task id', 'field': 'taskId'}, {'headerName': 'Info', 'field': 'info'}], 'rowData': [{'taskId': 1}]})
{'event_type': 'cellClicked', 'grid': 'ag-grid', 'id': 1, 'vue_type': 'grid', 'page_id': 0, 'websocket_id': 0, 'value': 1, 'rowIndex': 0, 'data': {'taskId': 1}, 'colId': 'taskId', 'selected': False, 'rowHeight': 28, 'session_id': '6e64e0654d1e48fa9e76c97e20681319', 'msg_type': 'event', 'page': Page(page_id: 0, number of components: 1, reload interval: None), 'websocket': <starlette.websockets.WebSocket object at 0x11f2ea470>, 'target': AgGrid(id: 1, vue_type: grid, Grid options: {'columnDefs': [{'headerName': 'Task id', 'field': 'taskId'}, {'headerName': 'Info', 'field': 'info'}], 'rowData': [{'taskId': 1}]})}
```

---

**Update for NiceGUI 1.0+**

Since version 1.0 NiceGUI doesn't use JustPy anymore. That's why there is no `view`. But it has now its own generic event subscription which can be used to subscribe to table events:

```py
table.on('cellClicked', handle_click)
```

[Here](https://www.ag-grid.com/javascript-data-grid/grid-events/) you can find a list of events with corresponding event arguments, most of which are accessible in Python.

Comment: Note that the API changed in NiceGUI 1.0, as discussed [here](https://github.com/zauberzeug/nicegui/issues/202). I'll update my answer accordingly.